# Windows 10 start button (and some programs) not working for some domain users

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, microsoft-surface-pro

We have a Surface Pro 2 that some users are using for their presentations. Recently other departments also wanted to try it out before buying their own. We had one of them login but some taskbar buttons are not showing up (ie. search bar, folder icon) and the start button does not even work. Only thing that works is being able to open the recycling bin. We then asked a user who never logged into the Surface before and his went it in fine. I've tried some of the stuff from here: https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/12321-taskbar-start-button-not-working.html but sfc scan didn't show any errors. My last guess is a group policy but wanted to make sure it is not that before I add/edit/remove policies on those departments.

Comment: Your question is a little broad.  Have you actually seen the behavior you describe in person?

Comment: @Ramhound Here's what I see: http://imgur.com/4qZ4R2Y.jpg. Here the start menu works also: http://imgur.com/5rWeBAE.jpg. Here the new user is logged in, one surface lets them in but buttons are disabled, notice how the search bar is missing: http://imgur.com/nTStqEY.jpg. and on the second one, it doesn't even go in.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it was updating or that there was a graphics driver crash. I had this recently happen on a computer at home where Windows 10 Pro had similar behaviour when it was pending a reboot after installing the Windows 10 updates and after a graphics card driver upgrade that was also wanting a reboot.

Rebooting seems to have fixed all the weird issues with the taskbar not showing or working correctly (I have a multi-monitor setup and one taskbar disappeared while the other wasn't properly responding to input)